# Choosing among graduate schools

Tags: graduate-school, engineering

I am an undergraduate student who has been admitted to three universities with full funding it is almost two weeks that I am stressing over my choices, therefore I decided to post my situation here to have your thoughts as well. I have been admitted to:

1. A high-rank Canadian University in Chemical Engineering MSc and my research will be related to Oil&Gas related fluid mechanics and simulation
2. A low-rank US University in Chemical Engineering MSc and my research will be about Oil&Gas related Molecular Dynamics and CFD simulations
3. A high-rank French graduate school in Renewable Energy Master

I am just left undecided between going to the US where a lot of opportunities are, or going to one of the top schools in my field in Canada or going to France but specialize in a rapidly growing Renewable Energy sector.

Thanks in advance for sharing your thoughts!

Comment: What are your post-masters goals?  This is key to answering your question.

Comment: My post-graduation plan is to work on industrial R&D in tackling energy-related challenges of the future.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, congrats! I don't have a full understanding of your situation, and my field of study isn't the same, but these might be some questions which might help you rank your options:

1. What's your post-graduation plan? Do you plan to get a PhD or start working after you finish your MSc? Knowing what you want to do with the degree will certainly help you see joining which university/lab will take you closer to your goal.
2. It's a research-based MSc: how much do you know about the lab you are going to be working with? Have you talked to the PIs of those labs personally? Can you request a brief online meeting with the lab members? Are they happy with the lab culture? What are former students from those labs doing now?
   In my opinion, the alignment of your research interests' and the lab's, and the lab culture are the most important.

Comment: My post-graduation plan is to work on industrial R&D in tackling energy-related challenges of the future.

Answer (score -2):

I am not sure if your field is different but currently I don't see any job opportunities in the States. I am also unsure if you are living in the US or not but with COVID related visa issues, it gets complicated to get even a student visa. I have university experience both in Canada and in the US (social sciences), and without any reservation, I would pick Canada (in Canada - US comparison). However, many factors play a role in a decision like this one (e.g., language barrier, further collaborations, daily life, support system etc). But imho US lacked many of these things for me.